# Cards not rendering when flutter web is deployed to a server (netlify)

Tags: flutter

I made a flutter app as my portfolio and Built it for web using canvaskit renderer using
`flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit`

The project runs perfectly fine when running on localhost debug mode.

I have made a custom widget HoverConatiner which contains card inside a container

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:awesome_icons/awesome_icons.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';

class HoverContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final String imagePath;
  final String gitLink;
  final String link;
  final String title;

  const HoverContainer({
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.gitLink,
    required this.link,
    required this.title,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _HoverContainerState createState() => _HoverContainerState();
}

class _HoverContainerState extends State<HoverContainer> {
  bool _isHovering = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isHovering = true;
        });
      },
      onDoubleTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isHovering = false;
        });
      },
      child: MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (event) {
          setState(() {
            _isHovering = true;
          });
        },
        onExit: (event) {
          setState(() {
            _isHovering = false;
          });
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          width: _isHovering ? widget.width * 1.1 : widget.width,
          height: _isHovering ? widget.height * 1.1 : widget.height,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.black,
            elevation: 50,
            shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 173, 19, 201),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
            child: Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    visible: _isHovering ? true : false,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.title,
                              style:  TextStyle(color: Colors.pink[400]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                launchUrlString(widget.gitLink);
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.github,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                launchUrlString(widget.link);
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.link,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Image.asset(widget.imagePath),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget is called inside homepage as

```
ResponsiveRowColumn(
                  rowMainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  rowPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  columnPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  layout: ResponsiveWrapper.of(context).isSmallerThan(DESKTOP)
                      ? ResponsiveRowColumnType.COLUMN
                      : ResponsiveRowColumnType.ROW,
                  children: const [
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: HoverContainer(
                        width: 410,
                        height: 280,
                        imagePath: 'assets/imag/E-commerce.png',
                        gitLink: 'https://github.com/Utkarsh4517/Flutter_E-commerce',
                        link: '',
                        title: 'Full Stack E-commerce app (development)',
                      ),
                    ),
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: HoverContainer(
                        width: 410,
                        height: 280,
                        imagePath: 'assets/imag/portfolio.png',
                        gitLink: 'https://github.com/Utkarsh4517/Portfolio',
                        link: '',
                        title: 'Personal Portfolio',
                      ),
                    ),
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: HoverContainer(
                        width: 410,
                        height: 280,
                        imagePath: 'assets/imag/weatherastic.png',
                        gitLink: 'https://github.com/Utkarsh4517/Weatherastic',
                        link: 'https://guileless-cassata-ad27ca.netlify.app/',
                        title: 'Weather App',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ResponsiveRowColumn(
                  rowMainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  rowPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  columnPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  layout: ResponsiveWrapper.of(context).isSmallerThan(DESKTOP)
                      ? ResponsiveRowColumnType.COLUMN
                      : ResponsiveRowColumnType.ROW,
                  children: const [
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: HoverContainer(
                        width: 410,
                        height: 280,
                        imagePath: 'assets/imag/unity.jpeg',
                        gitLink: '',
                        link: '',
                        title: 'Fun Arcade Game made with Unity (alpha)',
                      ),
                    ),
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: HoverContainer(
                        width: 410,
                        height: 280,
                        imagePath: 'assets/imag/comingsoon.png',
                        gitLink: '',
                        link: '',
                        title: 'Coming Soon!',
                      ),
                    ),
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                      rowFlex: 1,
                      child: HoverContainer(
                        width: 410,
                        height: 280,
                        imagePath: 'assets/imag/comingsoon.png',
                        gitLink: '',
                        link: '',
                        title: 'Coming Soon!',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

This is deployed on [link](https://curious-tanuki-aeb57f.netlify.app/#/)

Below is the expected output when running on localhost ....

[image]

If in case you are wondering why I am not using html renderer, because when I tried html renderer the Linier gradient text was also not showing along with the cards.

Github Link of Flutter project - [Click](https://github.com/Utkarsh4517/Portfolio)
Github Link of Build/web with canvaskit - [Click](https://github.com/Utkarsh4517/portfolio_web)

Thanks in advance!

I tried with both canvaskit and html renderer but both failed to render the cards as expected, I have already attached image of expected output.

Comment: I run 'flutter run -d chrome --release' and 'flutter run -d chrome --profile' then it is also not showing as the expected output, the images are shown only in debug mode. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Expanded widget and everything worked fine

Comment: It was the same issue for me. Wondering why... It worked normally while in debug mode and running locally.